# Single derivative in multiple variables

Tags: derivatives

Is it possible to take the derivative of multiple variables in a single derivative rather than in multiple partial derivatives? For example:
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta (xy)} (x^2y)$$

My first thought is to change variables such that $w = xy$, resulting in
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta w}(wx)$$ but $w$ is still dependent on $x$, which shows up in the differentiating term. 
Is what I'm thinking unnecessary in math or is there something to this?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: What does this even mean? Do you know the definition of a partial derivative? You must have a system of coordinates and then you fix all but one of the coordinates.